# Getting cumulative combinations (x choose y) for descending values of x in ordered consecutive list

Tags: python, math

I have a simple list `list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`. For any value x in the list (where x >= 4 to avoid an error), I need to get the cumulative number of possible "choose 4" combinations for each value `y`, where `y < x`.

For example, for `x = list[7]` I want to get the count of all cumulative choose 4 combinations for numbers <= 7, 6, 5 and 4, i.e. 7c4, 6c4, 5c4 and 4c4. These evaluate to 35, 15, 5 and 1, thus the cumulative count is 56.

I can do this by simply looping and getting the combinations:

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def ncr(n, r):
    r = min(r, n-r) 
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numer / denom

cumu_comb = 0
for i in list[:3:-1]:
    cumu_comb += ncr(i - 1, len(list) - i)
```

This feels like a slow / brute force method; with many millions of iterations, it's not going to be ideal. Is there a mathematical representation for finding the cumulative combinations for all values < x? Something like a factorial combinations function?

Comment: What is `reduce`? What is `op`? What are the cumulative combinations for all descending values < x ? Please provide an input/expected output.

Comment: this is very familiar to the *subset sum* problem, a NP-Hard problem in computer science... don't expect to do better then brute-force

Comment: I do not understand what `x` is in your problem statement. It is not clear in your description and there is no `x` in your code.

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by `cumulative combinations for all descending values < x` ? Also generaly combinations are used with positive numbers but `len(list)-i` could be smaller than 0. Does that make sense in that situation ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I've added some clarifications that hopefully address each.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using the combinations formula, easily.

[image]

For that reason, it might be considered more of a [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/) question, but I digress.

We can find the factorial of a number using `math.factorial()` rather than with a loop; as this uses C implementation, it will be much faster.

We can also use list comprehension to stuff this into one line, though I put inputs and outputs separately they could be bunched together. Keep in mind that I will not present a way to prevent errors in this code, as the question implies that we should be able to assume all *x* to be greater than 4.

To find the cumulative count we can write:

```py
import math

x = int(input("x: "))
a = sum([math.factorial(i)/(math.factorial(4) * math.factorial(i - 4)) for i in n[4:x+1]])
print(a)
```

For example, if we input `x` as 7:

- we will iterate through the list `[4, 5, 6, 7]`.
- Upon each of those elements we perform the combinations formula, with *k = 4* (as stated in the question, though this could be changed depending on one's circumstance, simply by changing the 4s). This goes into a list, due to our list iteration.
- Finally all the elements are added up.

This might be described as.

[image]

**it is important to note, that in this aim itself, one will be likely to handle enormous numbers. Depending on version, this might be a problem.**

Comment: Isn't this the same as the looping method shown as the "brute force" example in the question?

Comment: @HO similar, I suppose, but the main advantages over it are: a clear and probably faster formula, and using `math.factorial()` is faster as it uses C. Also it's in one line.

Comment: @HO That said, if you needed a fast way to do this, this would probably be a question better brought to the maths stack exchange - as I mentioned - which could probably help you more with finding a working formula. That or use a faster language.